# C++ - Need to pass a 2D array, but must be dynamically sized

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I am using a C++ library that requires that I pass it a 2D array.  Their code example gives a statically sized array like this:

```
double data[][2] = {
  { 10, 20, },
  { 13, 16, },
  { 7, 30, },
  { 15, 34, },
  { 25, 4, },
};
```

But I need to pass run-time sized data.  So I was attempting to do this:

```
  // unsigned numBins  is passed in to this function and set at run time

  double** binData = new double*[numBins];
  for(unsigned i=0; i < numBins; ++i) {
    binData[i] = new double[2];
  }
  //Set the data with something like
  //   binData[7][0] = 10;
  //   binData[7][1] = 100;

  //Later, diligently delete my data...
```

However, this fails in the library I am using.  It ends of graphing some garbage numbers.

I understand that arrays are not pointers.  And the library may be getting confused doing a "sizeof" somewhere.

If I am unable to change this library (it's 3rd party), how do I go about passing it dynamically sized data?

Thanks,
Maddie.

Comment: What's the method's signature?

Comment: If you don't care about performance, go for a vector of vectors. If you have a class that encapsulates that as a 1D dynamic array handy, use it instead. Either way, employing RAII will keep you from having to clean up.

Comment: if method accepts an array you can only pass array of the size declared. there is no way function can determine what size you actually passed as a parameter.

show the signature, ad will help alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the API expects a pointer to the first element of what it assumes is a flattened representation of a 2D array.

So the easy approach is as follows:

```
template<typename T>
struct FlatVectorAs2D {
private:
  size_t width;
  size_t height;
  std::vector<T> flat_vec;
public:
  std::vector<T>& base() { return flat_vec; }
  std::vector<T> const& base() const { return flat_vec; }
  size_t w() const { return width; }
  size_t h() const { return height; }
  T* operator[]( size_t index1 ) {
    return &flat_vec[index1*height];
  }
  T const* operator[]( size_t index1 ) const {
    return &flat_vec[index1*height];
  }
  FlatVectorAs2D( size_t w = 1, size_t h = 1 ):width(w), height(h) {
    flat_vec.resize(w*h);
  }
  void resize( size_t w, size_t h ) {
    width = w;
    height = h;
    flat_vec.resize(w*h);
  }
  T* raw() { return flat_vec.data(); }
  T const* raw() const { return flat_vec.data(); }
};
```

Use:

```
void api_function(double* d);
int main() {
  size_t width = 50;
  size_t height = 100;
  FlatVectorAs2D<double> buffer( width, height );
  buffer[0][1] = 1.0;
  api_function( buffer.raw() );
}
```

naturally this will depend on how exactly the API works.

But if my guess is right, this will help.

Comment: Your guess was correct indeed.  It was looking for a pointer to a flattened array.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
typedef double two_doubles[2];

int main()
{
    two_doubles * p = new two_doubles[300];

    // ...

    delete[] p;
}
```

Now `p` points to the first subarray of an array of 200 units of two doubles. That is, `p[i]` is a `double[2]`, and `p[i][0]`, `p[i][1]` are its member elements.

(Even better to use `std::unique_ptr<two_doubles[]> p(new two_doubles[300]);` and forget about the memory management.)